# Query with many tables works very long time in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have some models:

```
class TagToPublish(models.Model):
    tag_to_publish = models.TextField()
    ru_tag = models.TextField(blank=True)
    eng_tag = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_to_publish


class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.TextField(unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tag_to_publish = models.ForeignKey(TagToPublish, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    not_to_publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag

    def count(self):
        return self.gif_set.count()


class Gif(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField(unique=True)
    # link = models.ImageField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    tagged = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    to_publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    never_publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    choices = models.IntegerField(
        choices=[
            (1, 'To publish'),
            (2, 'Never Publish'),
            (0, 'Null')
            ], default=0)

    def image(self):
        return '<image src={} />'.format(self.link)

    image.allow_tags = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.link

    def tag_to_publish(self):
        for tag in self.tagged.all():
            tag_to_publish = tag.tag_to_publish
            if tag_to_publish:
                return tag_to_publish


class Order(models.Model):
    order_name = models.TextField(blank=True)


class InOrder(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    gif = models.ForeignKey(Gif)
    place_in_order = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to get a list with unique gif_links with the tag to publish.
I wrote this code:

```
tags = TagToPublish.objects.all()
tags_to_publish = Tag.objects.filter(tag_to_publish__in=tags)
gif_set = Gif.objects.filter(tagged__tag_to_publish__tag__in=tags_to_publish).distinct()[:100]
```

But it works very long time because each Gif can have many tags and different tags can have same TagToPublish. If use filter without distinct I got many duplicates.
Gif has about 180 000 items.

Tags have about 70 000 items.

TagToPublish has about 130 items.

Each Gif has up to 30 tags.

How can I solve this problem? For 100 unique items, it takes 30 seconds and 100% load two CPU cores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query can be dropped and your second replaced with

```
tags_to_publish = Tag.objects.filter(tag_to_publish__is_null=False)
```

which will give you all tags with a tag to publish. This saves you from having to do an expensive table join. Similarly your last query can be replaced with

```
gif_set = Gif.objects.filter(tagged__in=tags_to_publish).distinct()[:100]
```

which will again save you from table joins. As is, you have three or four joins in your query when you only need one, which is probably the source of the slowness.

Comment: You're right! Thank you! Now query works less 1 second!